# Is it correct to use a do-while loop inside a for loop? Why and why not?

Tags: c, for-loop, do-while

```
//program to count words
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int word = 0;
    char sent[] = "How are you doing mister";  //character pointer
    for (i = 0; sent[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            word++;

        } while (sent[i] == ' ');
    }
    printf("There are %d words in the sentence\n", word + 1);  //words are always 1 more than the no. of spaces.
    return 0;                                                  //or word=1;
}
```

This is a code for counting the number of words. Please tell me why cannot we use do-while loops inside a for loop. Or if we can, how to do it.

Comment: There are two ways to look at your question: (1) Syntactic form and (2) Logical correctness. Which part(s) are you not sure of?

Comment: `do
        {
            word++;

        } while (sent[i] == ' ');` is an infinite loop when `sent[i] == ' '` is true.

Comment: you can solve this on your own with a little debugging; put some output inside your `do{ ... } while` loop -- such as `printf("%c\n", sent[i]);` -- and you will soon see why it's not working the way you expect

Comment: ... even better : `printf("%d, %d, %c\n", i, word, sent[i]);`

Comment: @AnoushkaSharma: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

Nesting the various composite statements such as `for` and `do`/`while` is allowed in C at least up to 127 levels, as specified in **5.2.4.1 Translation limits**.

The problem is not a syntax issue, but rather a conceptual one:

- your `do`/`while` loop iterates on a constant condition as neither `i`, nor `sent` is modified in the body or in the condition of the loop, leading to an infinite loop if `sent[i]` is a space.
- counting spaces is not a correct approach to counting words in a string: `""` has `0` words, not `1` per your intended code, `" "` also but you would get `2` and `"A  B"` only has `2` words, not `3`.
- you should count the number of transitions from space to non space, starting with an implicit space before the beginning of the string.
- note also that `char sent[] = "...";` is **not** a character pointer, but a character array.

Here is a modified version:

```
//program to count words
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, words, last;
    char sent[] = "How are you doing mister?";

    words = 0;
    last = ' ';
    for (i = 0; sent[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (sent[i] != ' ' && last == ' ')
            word++;
        last = sent[i];
    }
    printf("There are %d words in the sentence '%s'\n", words, sent);
    return 0;
}
```

In my experience proof reading code, `do`/`while` loops tend to be written incorrectly, especially by beginners, missing test conditions or broken in some other way. I you think a `do`/`while` loop solves a given problem, think again, a `for` loop might be a safer approach. The only place `do`/`while` loops are needed is in a macro expansion where you want to combine multiple statements into a single compound statement:

```
#define swap_ints(a, b)  do { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; } while (0)
```

Note however that the swapping method in this macro is inefficient and macros are very error prone and should be avoided even more than `do`/`while` loops :)

Answer (score 1):

It is completely valid to nest a `do-while` loop within a `for` loop.  Syntactically, there is nothing wrong with your program.

However, as others have described, your nested loop will never terminate when `sent[i] == ' '`.  Your program has bugs, but they have nothing to do with the validity of nesting loops.